# How can I create a dataframe of movies X genres using the original dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I'm using movielens database and I need to create a dataframe about movies X genres in python. In other words, I need to transform the dataframe in a new binary dataframe.

[image: This is the original dataframe]

[image: This is the dataframe I need to be created]

How can I do this in a optimized way?

Comment: Don't post DataFrames as images, post them as text

Comment: `df.set_index('movieID').genres.str.get_dummies(sep='|').reset_index()`

Comment: Thank you ALollz! It was exactly what I needed!

Comment: @Mariana Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your comment flag has been declined. Please read about [how to flag comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373801/when-is-a-comment-hostile-or-unfriendly-educating-newer-users-how-to-flag-comm).